# Images not dragging to new picture box

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop picture boxes to a new picture box.

The code I have used but was wondering if any more code is needed to allow drga and drop.

```
public void mouseEvents()    
    {
        // Allow mouse down
        pbMIDI.MouseDown += pb1_MouseDown;

        // Set picture poxes to allow drop
        dragTo1.AllowDrop = true;

        // Allow enter and drop on each picture box
        drop1.DragEnter += drag1_DragEnter;
        drop1.DragDrop += drop1_DragDrop;
    }


// MIDI Drag and Drop
    private void pb1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var img = pbMIDI.Image;
        if (img == null) return;
        if (DoDragDrop(img, DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            pbMIDI.Image = null;
        }
    }
    void drag1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
    void drop1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        drop1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

mouseEvents called in pictureScreen():

```
public pictureScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mouseEvents();
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying this works?  Or is there a question?

Comment: It isnt working, and I was wondering if there is any more code needed

Comment: What's dragTo1?  Shouldn't that be drop1?  Where are you calling MouseEvents?

Comment: yes it is, i just didnt copy it right

Comment: Mouse event is called:   public pictureScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mouseEvents();
        }

Comment: See [How to Allow Drag and Drop on pictureBox?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/360629bb-633c-4eeb-92a4-0af75de893fd/how-to-allow-drag-and-drop-on-picturebox?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Comment: I got this working, I have mouseEvents(); in the wrong place.

Comment: Does anyone know how to add scoring when doing this. I would like to add one to a variable when the image is correctly dropped.